# Unable to build CodedUI sln with VS2017 buildtools,type or namespace name 'UITesting' does not exist in the namespace Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools

Tags: visual-studio-2017, coded-ui-tests, azure-pipelines-build-task

We have Visual Studio build task to build Coded UI solution, and Visual studio 2017 build tools are installed on the build agent. Compilation fails with the following errors:

Error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'UITesting' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Do we need to install VS 2017 on the build agent to resolve this issue, or there is any other alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install VS 2017, you can just install part components (just check **Coded UI test** components, it will add necessary components)